# Autocomplete with the same name but different id

Tags: php

i'm writing a php script which selects all the names inside of the test table using a autocomplete textfield.

Ex.

```
table name = test

id   name   address   city
1    john   test 1
2    john   test 2
3    mike
4    mary
```

Because there are more then one john, when i select it i have as result the same address. So if i'm writing john it shows two john but if i select the first one or the second one the address still the same. How i can solve this issue.

Hope you can help me .

Let me know if you need more information

Thanks,

Roberto

Comment: what plugin are you using for autocomplete? can you show us some code that you have tried

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery for autocompletion, then take a look here.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152558/jQuery-UI-Autocomplete-with-ID